# Mobile additional dac don't refresh

Tags: acumatica

I have a refresh problem with a container Link.
When I open the container (PIPELINE & CRM) the first time, the values ​​are good, if I go to another customer, the container (PIPELINE & CRM) takes over the data from the previous customer. When I add a record to the container the screen updates good.

The screen works perffectly in the ERP
[image]

https://youtu.be/xLNOYNXjklU

I use this code on the mobile

```
update screen AR303000 {
    update container "CustomerSummary" {
    add recordAction "save"
    update layout "CustomerHeader"
      {
      }
    update layout "OtherTab" {  
    displayName = "CRM"              
    add containerLink "PIPELINE"
  }
      }
  add container "PIPELINE" {
 fieldsToShow = 4
    displayName = "Pipeline"
    listActionsToExpand = 2
    containerActionsToExpand = 2
    add field "Date"         
    add field "Origine"
    add field "Raison"
    add field "Statut"
    add field "Article"
    add field "Description"    
    add field "Commentaire"        
 add containerAction "Insert" {
 icon = "system://Plus"
 behavior = Create
 redirect = True
 }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, it was located in the pxselect of the currentpipeline